# Error in publishing to RPubs from Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, publish

I installed the latest version of RStudio (RStudio 1.1.423 - Windows Vista / 7/8/10).
I'm trying to publish to RPubs, but in Global Options does not appear the option for Rpubs.
When I request Publish Document, the following error appears: Error occurred while executing method.

Rprofile:
I entered the command: options (rpubs.upload.method = "internal") at line 25 of Rprofile, but it did not resolve.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is provided by a careful rereading of http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/25030_8e9c9ffc3b3c423d9381d81543423502.html

"Put in options(rpubs.upload.method = “internal”) and no other text at all". Meaning that this line of code is the only code present in the .Rprofile file.

Previously I had been adding the line to a copy of the rest of the Rprofile text. The unnecessary code was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error before. Turns out it was due to having an accent mark in a folder name from my directory (í). I just modified that one folder name and it worked fine.

Comment: It can also be because of an accent in the file name