# Variety of Errors leaflet upload to RPubs

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been trying to get this to work for hours and cannot get it to work.

I am creating data frames from a large series of excel sheets essentially, then creating interactive leaflet maps to display the data.

The problem is coming from the maps, I can knit/run all of the data and it comes out into the viewer window perfectly fine, but when I try to upload to Rpubs I get a variety of errors.

Mostly it is an error 18

> curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
>   Error in http(protocol, "api.rpubs.com", port, method, path, headers,  : 
>     Curl request failed (curl error 18 occurred)
>   Calls:  -> http

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and R Studio multiple times

Uninstalled and reinstalled all packages.  I have reduced the number of maps to only 1 with layers instead but it just won't work...

I really don't know how to show a small amount of code to do this but here is my leaflet code.

```
# Create the popup dialog for both layers

final_district_dataframe_popups_sfsp <- paste0(
  "District Name: ", final_district_dataframe$sfa_name, "<br>",
  "Free and Reduced Percent: ", round(final_district_dataframe$free_and_red_perc, digits = 3), "<br>",
  "SFSP Site Count: ", final_district_dataframe$site_count_sfsp, "<br>",
  "SFSP Average ADP: ", final_district_dataframe$adp_sfsp_2018)

final_district_dataframe_popups_score <- paste0(
  "District Name: ", final_district_dataframe$sfa_name, "<br>",
  "Free and Reduced Percent: ", round(final_district_dataframe$free_and_red_perc, digits = 3), "<br>",
  "Score: ", round(final_district_dataframe$score, digits = 3), "<br>", 
  "School Breakfast Program: ", final_district_dataframe$sbp, "<br>",
  "National School Lunch Program: ", final_district_dataframe$nslp, "<br>",
  "Afterschool Snack Program: ", final_district_dataframe$snack, "<br>",
  "Special Milk Program: ", final_district_dataframe$smp)

# Create the color pallet for each layer

sfsp_pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", 
                                domain = 
score_pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", 
                                domain = final_district_dataframe$score)

# create the map

layer_map <- final_district_dataframe %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "+init=epsg:4326") %>% 
  leaflet(width = "100%" ,options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 6)) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>% 
  setView(lng = -106, lat = 39.6, zoom = 6.5) %>% 
    addPolygons(popup = final_district_dataframe_popups_score,
              group = "Score",
              stroke = FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0,
              fillOpacity = 0.6,
              color = ~ score_pal(score),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            group = "Score",
            pal = score_pal, 
            values = ~ score,
            title = "Evaluated Risk Score",
            opacity = 1) %>% 
  addPolygons(popup = final_district_dataframe_popups_sfsp,
              group = "SFSP",
              stroke = FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0,
              fillOpacity = 0.6,
              color = ~ sfsp_pal(adp_sfsp_2017),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            group = "SFSP",
            pal = sfsp_pal, 
            values = ~ adp_sfsp_2017,
            title = "adp_sfsp_2017",
            opacity = 1) %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("Score", "SFSP"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE, position = "topleft")) %>% 
  hideGroup("SFSP")

layer_map
```

I am trying to publish to html.  Like the below but continue to get errors:

The earlier portion of the code before the maps are created

http://rpubs.com/cherritt/488395

Comment: You already modified your .Rprofile? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990770/error-in-publishing-to-rpubs-from-rstudio

Comment: I am not sure I know what that means...  I looked over the question you referenced and still don't understand what the .Rprofile is

Comment: @J_F can you expand on that a little bit?  I am really needing a solution, literally been working on this for 8 hours now.

Comment: @J_F I finally figured out how to do the .Rprofile, unfortunately still no luck.